# RemoveAt function in C giving error that 'T' does not contain a definition for RemoveAT

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

My remove at function is giving a strange error. Error code is CS1061.
[image]

Here is the code I am trying to implement

```
 public bool Remove(T element)
    {
        // You should replace this plug by your code.
        int index = Array.IndexOf(data, element);
        Boolean result;

   

        if (data.Contains(element))
        {
            data[index].RemoveAt(element);
            result = true;

        }

        else
            result = false;

        return result;

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        
    }
```

Purpose of this code is to: Remove the first occurrence of the specified amount from the data collection. It returns true if the item is successfully removed. This method returns false if item was not found in the Vector

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: What data type is `data`?

Comment: actually you would call `RemoveAt` on the collection and not on a single element inside the collection. Whiyh is what you are doing by this: `data[index]`. It should look like this: `data.RemoveAt(index)`

Comment: I did try doing Data.RemoveAt(Index) gave the same error. So that might not be the issue...

Comment: could you please supply a sample that shows what `data` etc. are?

Comment: if `Data.RemoveAt(Index)` gave you the same error there is something wrong outside of this sample, like data being of type T, but it should to be something like `List<T>`

Comment: What `RemoveAt` method did you think you were attempting to invoke? Given no complaint from that `Array.IndexOf` method call, we can surmise that `data` is `T[]`. Well, arrays don't have a `RemoveAt` method.

Comment: T[] newData = new T[data.Length + extraCapacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) newData[i] = data[i];
            data = newData;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if I cant use RemoveAt method, which alternate method should I use?

Comment: Why not make it a List<T> rather than a T[]?

Comment: Or, actually, why not throw this class away and use List<T> instead of it? (As opposed to this class having a List<T> and a Remove method that calls List's Remove - in other words; this class seems to be a proxy to a collection - why not just use the collection? If it's not good enough, write some extension methods?)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line:

```
data[index].RemoveAt(element);
```

`data[index]` refers to the T element, not the array of T elements. Also, Array objects do not support the RemoveAt method, so instead of using an array of type `T[]`, you should use `List<T>`, which supports the RemoveAt method.

The previous line should read:

```
data.RemoveAt(index);
```

I also recommend using type constraints so T should implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface, so the Contains method can work correctly as you expect, and you could use:

```
data.Remove(element);
```

Comment: Did not work, gave same error

Comment: Error code CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required format parameter 'value' of CollectionExtentions.Remove<Tkey, TValue>, TKey, out TValue)'

Comment: @FerryRarri Tkey and TValue? now that sounds like you're using a `Dictionary`... wich you surely didn't use before.... could please just provide enough code?